# How should I handle the single quote in a form to help protect against SQL injection, using WebMatrix razor (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, razor, sql-injection, webmatrix

Currently I simply don't allow apostrophe's at all (along with other character's as you can see) with this, reiterated for each field:

```
foreach(char c in Comments)
    {
        if(c=='\'' || c=='$' || c=='\"' || c=='&' || c=='%' || c=='@' || c=='-' || c=='<' || c=='>')
        {
            errorMessage = "You have entered at least one invalid character in the \"Comments\" field. Invalid characters are: [\'], [\"], [&], [$], [@], [-], [<], [>], and [%]";
        }
    }
```

I've been coding this for a while, and I am getting better, but the real problem is that, while I am sure there is a way to effectively "strip-out" or otherwise validate the user input, I am not sure which approach is best and probably wouldn't until a security crisis was imminent.

If I have to, I will settle on simply never allowing single quotes into the form at all (as it is now), however this may aggravate anyone named say... Bill O'Reilly for the name field, etc., etc.

There are probably other (well I don't know what to call them, 'plug-ins?' 'outside programs?') that would do the job for me, but that is virtually useless since not only do I have no idea how to integrate that, I would have no idea how to tailor it specifically to my web interface/database.

Is there any code that could help me detect a sql injection apostrophe (by the characters surrounding it maybe?) from a normal apostrophe?  Keep in mind some of my fields can hold up to 500 characters (textareas) and one up to 1,000.

Thanks for any ideas or help!

Comment: Just use parameterized queries, then it won't be an issue.

Comment: See SqlCommand.Parameters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No amount of input encoding/cleanup will be as safe as parametrized queries.

See [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for details on parametrized queries.

```
string commandText = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE CustomerID = @ID;";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    //.....
}
```

Comment: Wait, is that the placeholder thing?  where you use @1, @2, @3, etc?
If so, I already use those everywhere I can, but that doesn't seem to help me with the SELECT statement.  Is there any example for using this with SELECT statement?  I think the example I used may simply not have used them there.

Comment: @VoidKing, maybe you should update your question then... It looks like your problem is different from what you've stated originally, should it be "why my SELECT still have SQL injection problems even if I use parametrized queries"? Sample of your code would help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't realize the example of SQL SELECT statement I had didn't use the parameterized queries example.  I do however already have this implemented with all instances of UPDATE and INSERT for my web interface.  Thanks for letting me know I could do that with SELECT statement as well, though your example looks beyond my current understanding, so a simpler example using db.Query(selectString, param1, param2, etc...) would have been nicer.  Thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Injections is not a problem with the input containing specific characters, it's a problem with how you handle the input.

By disallowing certain characters you can stop the obvious ways to cause SQL injections, but it's virtually impossible to use that to stop all possible ways.

If encoded correctly, there are no character that causes problems. The best way of doing that for database calls is to use parameterised queries, so that the database driver takes care of encoding the correct characters according to the data type and the specific database.

Also, you need to encode the values correctly when you use them later on, like HTML encoding strings that are put in HTML code, URL encoding strings that are used in an URL (and both for strings that are put in an URL in the HTML code.)

Comment: Any examples of what you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You should use parameterised queries to prevent SQL Injection as other people have already said.

Alexei Levenkov provides a good example of using ADO.NET parameters, but more commonly, you will use the [Database Helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569069%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) when working with WebMatrix Razor pages (ASP.NET Web Pages Framework) where parameter handling is slightly different. The [Database.Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.query%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method (Query(string commandText, params object[] parameters) takes a string representing the SQL to be executed, and an array of objects, representing the parameter values to be passed to the SQL. The Database helper expects parameter markers to start at @0, and increment by 1 each time e.g.

```
var sql = "SELECT * From MyTable WHERE TheDate > @0 AND ID > @1";
```

Then you pass actual values in the following manner:

```
var data = Database.Open("MyDb").Query(sql, Request["date"], Request["id"]);
```

Internally, the Database class takes care of matching values to placeholders and creating ADO.NET parameters for you.